# C# Should we use "byte.MinValue" or "0" in comparing counts?

Tags: c#, .net

In C# Should we use "byte.MinValue" or "0" in comparing counts?

Which of the following is efficient and why?

```
if(customCollection.Count > byte.MinValue)
{//do something
}
```

OR

```
if(customCollection.Count > 0)
{//do something
}
```

Comment: why would you do that? Maybe you should use `string.Empty.Length`? It will be also 0

Comment: Beacuse of readability I prefer to use 0 or Linq Any() method customCollection.Any()

Comment: There is no difference.just byte.minValue is const with 0 value

Comment: @PiotrCzarnecki yeah, Any can be more readable, but byte.MinValue?

Comment: If someone asked you "how many elements are there in an empty collection", would you answer "0" or "the same number as the minimum value that an unsigned byte can hold"?

Comment: @wudzik - I have never seen that way of comparison, so for me it looks awkward, I don't have opinion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`MinValue` is constant defined in `Byte` class as

```
public const byte MinValue = 0;
```

So it doesn't matter from efficiency point of view how will you use it.

Using `0` instead of `byte.MinValue` looks better from readability point of view.

Comment: Thanks, Do you think there is any compile time performance improvement while using "0" instead of "byte.MinValue"? Not sure but just for curiosity checking if thinking in correct way

Comment: Since it is defined as `const` - compiler in fact will replace any occurences of `byte.MinValue` to `0` in the code generated during compile time. So if you're using `MinValue` - it will take slightly more time for compiler to proceed your code. But really - who cares about few milliseconds of compile time?

Comment: Thanks Andy that is what i was expecting :)

Answer (score 2):

Using `byte.MinValue` in this way is non-intuitive.

The reader has to think too hard about the implications. Use `0`, a constant defined as zero (and named as such) if you're morally opposed to magic numbers in code, or use `customCollection.Any()` presuming `customCollection` is an `IEnumerable<T>`, but don't use `byte.MinValue` this way.

Consider the "principle of least surprise," or the "principle of least astonishment" here.